# How can I insert a record and update it at the same time in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a record but update one of its data at the same time. For example, I'm gonna insert a new record but what I am inserting already exists in the table, I'm just gonna update something let's say the id.

```
start transaction;
INSERT INTO notification (user_id,notify_to,activity,date) SELECT     
user_id,notify_to,activity,date FROM notification;
UPDATE notification SET user_id='4';
commit;
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work. Instead of just updating this new record I'm inserting, it rather updates every record. Is there some thing I can do to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a real query?

Comment: side note: the `user_id` column is probably an integer field, which does not require single quote at `user_id='4'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to duplicate all records in the table but have `user_id` set to 4 for all the new records, try the following...

```
INSERT INTO notification (user_id, notify_to, activity, date)
SELECT 4, notify_to, activity, date FROM notification;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an unique index on this specific data where you are expecting duplicates (you say the data exists, so there must be a duplicate situation).

Then use the following query to insert or update the data:

```
INSERT INTO notification (user_id,notify_to,activity,date) SELECT     
user_id,notify_to,activity,date FROM notification ON DUPLICATE UPDATE  user_id='4';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the where clause:

```
UPDATE notification SET user_id='4' WHERE ...
```

With no where clause you effectively update all records.